$u+v$ is invertible and $uv=0$. Then $\operatorname{rank}(u)+\operatorname{rank}(v)=\dim V$
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vectorspace over a field $\mathbb K$ and $u,v:V\to V$ are two linear transformations such that $u+v$ is invertible and $uv=0$. Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(u)+\operatorname{rank}(v)=\dim V$.
I'm going to be using these two basic  inequalities$$\operatorname{rank}(u)+\operatorname{rank}(v)\ge \operatorname{rank}(u+v)$$
$$\operatorname{rank} (u○v)\le \operatorname {rank}u$$
We have $$\dim(V)=\dim((u+v)○(u+v)^{-1})\le \operatorname {rank}(u+v)\le \operatorname{rank}(u)+\operatorname{rank}(v)$$
Now we're left to prove $\dim(V)\ge\operatorname{rank}(u)+\operatorname{rank}(v)$ and we should somehow figure out a way to use the condition $uv=0$.

Are you not allowed to use the rank-nullity theorem?

@J.Dmaths you're allowed.

By the rank-nullity theorem:
$$rank(v)+nullity(v)= dim V$$
Also, it follows that:  im(u) is a subspace of ker(v),as :
$$\forall \mathbf{v} \in im(u), v(\mathbf{v})=0 $$
by the given fact.
So$$dim(V)=rank(v)+nullity(v)\geq rank(v) +rank(u)$$
You deduced already that:
$$dim (V) \leq rank(v)+ rank(u)$$
So equality must hold.

The condition says $uv=u\times v=0$

Ah sorry I took it to mean composition, I'll have a think about it and amend the answer.

Actually now that I thought about it I think they meant $u○v$ instead of $uv$ because otherwise it doesn't make sense.
